# Put transparent navbar on top of jumbotron - Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make a landing page with a big jumbotron at the top and a transparent navbar placed on top of it, like this: https://stripe.com/en-gb-dk. The jumbotron just has a coloured background (i.e. no background image). I have tried `fixed-top`, which achieves the desired effect; however, I'm not interested in the navbar being fixed to the top (i.e. follow the page on scroll) - I'm just interested in the transparent navbar being on top of the jumbotron. Does anyone know how I can achieve this using bootstrap? Thanks!

Below is my code (I use Bootstrap in conjunction with React)

Navbar:

```
<nav className={`navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-transparent`}>
  <div className="container-fluid">
    <a className="navbar-brand">
      <img src="/images/logo.png" alt="" className="img-fluid" />
    </a>
    <button
      onClick={() => setShowMenu(!showMenu)}
      className="navbar-toggler"
      type="button"
      data-toggle="collapse"
      data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup"
      aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup"
      aria-expanded="false"
      aria-label="Toggle navigation"
    >
      <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div className={`collapse navbar-collapse ${showMenu ? "show" : ""}`}>
      <div className="navbar-nav mx-auto">
        <li className="nav-item active">
          <a className="nav-link" href="#">
            Link 1
          </a>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item active">
          <a className="nav-link" href="#">
            Link 2
          </a>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item active">
          <a className="nav-link" href="#">
            Link 3
          </a>
        </li>
      </div>
      <div className="nav navbar-nav nav-right">
        <li className="nav-item active">
          <a className="nav-link" href="#">
            Link 4
          </a>
        </li>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <style jsx>
    {`
      .navbar .navbar-collapse {
        text-align: center;
      }
      @media (min-width: 992px) {
        .nav-right {
          float: right;
        }
      }
    `}
  </style>
</nav>
```

Jumbotron:

```
<section> 
<div className="main-jumbotron">
  <h1>Let us help you find your next  expert</h1>
  <h4>
    At beautykonect, we have the best  experts ready to help you
  </h4>
  <div className="text-center mt-5">
    <button className="btn btn-primary btn-lg outline">Get started</button>
  </div>
  <svg
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    viewBox="0 0 100 100"
    preserveAspectRatio="none"
  >
    <polygon fill="white" points="0,100 100,0 100,100" />
  </svg>
</div>
<style jsx>
  {`
    svg {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 10vw;
    }
    .main-jumbotron {
      position: relative;
      height: 90vh;
      min-height: 300px;
      background: rgb(255, 216, 223);
      background: linear-gradient(
        90deg,
        rgba(255, 216, 223, 1) 0%,
        rgba(252, 189, 201, 1) 53%,
        rgba(255, 134, 157, 1) 100%
      );
    }
    .main-jumbotron h1 {
      padding-top: 125px;
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
      font-weight: 700;
    }
    .main-jumbotron h4 {
      color: white;
      margin-top: 25px;
      font-weight: 600;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .btn.outline {
      background: none;
      padding: 12px 22px;
    }
    .btn-primary.outline {
      border: 2px solid #fff;
      color: #fff;
    }
    .btn-primary.outline:hover,
    .btn-primary.outline:focus,
    .btn-primary.outline:active,
    .btn-primary.outline.active,
    .open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary {
      color: rgba(252, 189, 201, 1);
      border-color: #fff;
      background-color: #fff;
    }
    .btn-primary.outline:active,
    .btn-primary.outline.active {
      border-color: #007299;
      color: #007299;
      box-shadow: none;
    }
  `}
</style>
<section>
```

[This is what it looks like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3nWj.png)

What I want to do then is to make the navbar transparent and push the banner/jumbotron up, such that there is no white section at the top of the page

Edit: added code and photo

Comment: Please post your current code. Explaining it orally might not lead to the desired solution.

Comment: I've added the code now @m4n0 -  thanks!

Comment: Good but does that produce the intended output that you explain? You said you are using React then make use of https://codesandbox.io/s/ to show the demo.

Comment: I have added an image now @m4n0. This is what it looks like now -  as I'm not able to produce the intended output (hence this SO question), I unfortunately can't show anything on codesandbox. Hope it's clearer now

Comment: The image is a bit different from the code provided; however, it should serve to make the problem clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap provides a utility class `position-absolute` which will give the desired result but it does not have classes to handle specific positioning properties such as top.

This solution follows the same approach as the example, apply this new style rule in the inline style for the navbar:

```
.navbar {
        position: absolute; // could use 'position-absolute' on navbar instead
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%; // could also use class 'w-100' on navbar instead
}
```

Comment: This does not have the intended effect I'm afraid - it only moves the nav links to the top; it doesn't make the navbar transparent

Comment: Ah, that's my bad. These styles should be applied to solely the `.navbar` not `.navbar-collapse` in the inline style. I'll edit the answer.